# Why the value cannot be found for Scala form?

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, compiler-errors

I have the following Scala class which I believe should define the structure and constraints for a form

```
package controllers

import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._
class UserLogin{
case class UserLogin (username: String, password: String)
val userForm= Form(mapping("username" -> nonEmptyText(5,25),"password" -> nonEmptyText(5,25))(UserLogin.apply)(UserLogin.unapply)
)
}
```

I then also have this Scala.html file for constructing the form

```
@import helper._
@index("Login")

@(userForm: play.data.Form[UserLogin])
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.home) {
@helper.inputText(userForm("username"). id -> "username")
@helper.inputPassword(userForm("password"), id -> "password")
}
```

I have been using the tutorial to help me http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaForms

The problem is with the scala.html file here  `@(userForm: play.data.Form[UserLogin])` The userForm is giving the following compilation error `not found: value userForm`

Any suggestions to fix this will be appreciated.

Comment: why you uses {} after caseclass?? and where is your controller method

Comment: I'm not too sure on the scala syntax, but have tried `class UserLogin { case class UserLogin (username: String, password: String)
val userForm= Form(mapping("username" -> nonEmptyText(5,25),"password" -> nonEmptyText(5,25))(UserLogin.apply)(UserLogin.unapply)
)
} ` But have the same problem. Which controller class do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your main issues are with incorrect syntax in your HTML template, rather than in your case class.

According to the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTemplates), your template's parameters need to be declared right at the top of the template file:

```
@(userForm: play.data.Form[UserLogin])
```

followed by any import statements:

```
@import helper._
```

and then the rest of your HTML template.

Assuming that `index` is a main layout template that takes in a `String` and some `Html`, I think your HTML template needs to look something like this:

```
@(userForm: play.data.Form[UserLogin])

@import helper._

@index("Login") {

  @helper.form(action = routes.Application.home) {
    @helper.inputText(userForm("username"). id -> "username")
    @helper.inputPassword(userForm("password"), id -> "password")
  }
}
```